# "No suitable constructor for simple type" with Jackson in Android and objects inside another

Tags: android, json, parsing, constructor, jackson

I'm using Jackson in my project to parse the JSON received from the server, the parse step works very well, the problem comes when trying to use the nested objects. Here is some code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Song {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id = 0;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title = "";
    @JsonProperty("link")
    private String link = "";
    @JsonProperty("album")
    private Album album;

    public Song() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
       return link ;
    }

    public void setLink(String link ) {
        this.link = link ;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(Album album) {
        this.album = album;
    }
}
```

The Album class looks like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Album {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("artist")
    private Artist artist;

    public Album(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Artist getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }
}
```

And finally the "Artist" class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Artist{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    public Artist() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So, as I said before the JSON parsing works well the problem is when I try to access to one of the "sub" objects, if I try to get the artist name for example. When I do:

```
getSong().getAlbum().getArtist().getName();
```

It doesn't matter where I do it, Jackson stops parsing the JSON giving:

```
(IOException)Error: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.zarpamos.fandanztap.model.Album]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Plain JSON output:

```
{"categories":[{"id":"1","name":"Pop","packs":[{"id":"2","songs":[{"album":{"id":"2","title":"Sex And Love","artist":{"id":"2","name":"Enrique Iglesias"}},"id":"3","title":"Bailando","link":"song_1.mp3"},{"album":{"id":"1","title":"Peace Is The Mission","artist":{"id":"3","name":"Major Lazer"}},"id":"6","title":"Powerful","link":"song_2.mp3"},{"album":{"id":"2","title":"Sex And Love","artist":{"id":"2","name":"Enrique Iglesias"}},"id":"4","title":"Loco","link":"song_3.mp3"}, // More JSON elements...
```

Parsing "categories" and "packs" works very well the problem is inside "album".

Same JSON output but stylized:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Pop
                    [packs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [songs] => Array                // Here starts the songs JSON array, where the error is produced
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array                // song
                                                (
                                                    [album] => Array            // album
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 2
                                                            [title] => Sex And Love
                                                            [artist] => Array           // artist
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 2
                                                                    [name] => Enrique Iglesias
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [id] => 3
                                                    [title] => Bailando
                                                    [link] => song_1.mp3
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [album] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1
                                                            [title] => Peace Is The Mission
                                                            [artist] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 3
                                                                    [name] => Major Lazer
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [id] => 6
                                                    [title] => Powerful
                                                    [link] => song_2.mp3
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [album] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 2
                                                            [title] => Sex And Love
                                                            [artist] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 2
                                                                    [name] => Enrique Iglesias
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [id] => 4
                                                    [title] => Loco
                                                    [link] => song_3.mp3
                                                )
                // More array elements...
```

Here is the Stack trace:

```
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1080)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:142)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.dolphinziyo.myapp.tasks.GetPacksTask.onPostExecute(GetPacksTask.java:93)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.dolphinziyo.myapp.tasks.GetPacksTask.onPostExecute(GetPacksTask.java:38)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is really weird and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone tell me where is the error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That isn't JSON output, looks more like a PHP object? It's odd that you're getting an error when *accessing* the object, can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: That is the JSON output printed (from PHP) to be more readable, I decided to show this instead of the plain JSON. I'm going to see if I can print an stacktrace

Comment: I updated my post with the same piece of JSON code but now in plain text.

Comment: I just added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

In your `Album` class, you must have a setter for `Artist` attribute like this :

```
 public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
 }
```

not like this :

```
 public void setArtist(**Artista** artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
 }
```

Comment: This was an spelling error when translating my code to StackOverflow, i wrote the code in spanish. I already fixed my post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally parsed it manually until I have more time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Are your classes top-level types or nested in another class? If they're nested, you need to mark them as 'static'

Comment: They are nested as I show in the code, "Artist" is nested in "Album" and "Album" is inside "Song", I'm going to try doing them static, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, they are top level (as in the provided code) not nested. Anyway I tried doing them static but the app fails with Null Pointer Exception.